# Google Pay Offer Passes not expiring

Tags: android, google-pay

We're creating Google Offer Passes for an initiative. According to the documentation passes can be expired by setting the `validTimeInterval`  field in the Offer Object JSON. The doc says:

> The time period this object will be active and object can be used. An
> object's state will be changed to expired when this time period has
> passed.

But all the passes I've tried are still in **active** status even after the end time has clearly passes. I tried having the date in UTC timezone, date with an offset as well as without an offset. None of them seem to work.

Has anyone experienced this?

- https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/rest/v1/offerobject
- https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/rest/v1/TimeInterval
- https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/rest/v1/DateTime

Comment: Please include the JSON of the pass object you are sending to Google. Perhaps there's something wrong with your format. In my tests - offer passes were moved to the "Expired Passes" list shortly after their expiration timestamp has passed. I used something like this in my JSON:  `"validTimeInterval": {
    "start": {
      "date": "2023-04-27T05:48:00Z"
    },
    "end": {
      "date": "2023-05-15T07:00:00Z"
    }
  },`

Answer (score 0):

if they are expired, gpay displays them in the expiration passes area